# Userscript runs forever (Continuously reloads page, instead of redirecting once)

Tags: javascript, userscripts, tampermonkey

I'm running into a problem executing a Userscript in Chrome using Tampermonkey.

The idea of the script is to append the string `&f=%20license:"Creative+Commons+0"` to the url `freesound.org/search` in case it doesn't find it there.

The problem is the userscript keeps appending the string endlessly when it should do it once.

Here's the code:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Freesound CC0
// @match        https://freesound.org/search*
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
     if (!window.location.href.match(/f=%20license:"Creative+Commons+0"/)) {
         window.location.href += '&f=%20license:"Creative+Commons+0"';
     }
})();
```

Comment: I'm sure there is a dupe for the URL-encoding part of this answer too.  Will try to remember to find it, later.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this regex

```
f=%20license:"Creative\+Commons\+0"
```

notice the backslash before the plus symbols

Answer (score 1):

Two (or possibly three) problems:

- The character `"` in the string you're appending to the URL gets encoded as `%22`, which the regex won't match on the next iteration.
- You need to escape the `+` inside the regex.
- Uppercase characters in a URL may get changed to lowercase by the server; you may need to make the regex case-insensitive (using the `i` flag).

This should work:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
     if (!window.location.href.match(/f=%20license:%22Creative\+Commons\+0%22/i)) {
         window.location.href += '&f=%20license:%22Creative+Commons+0%22';
     }
})();
```

Comment: An additional problem is that some servers still will lower-case URL's, so `Creative+Commons` becomes `creative+commons`.  If that is the OP's case then the `i` flag is needed in the regex.

Comment: ah, good point! Added that to the answer